# how to write case statement using python

Tags: python

I have column called **category**

SCRIPT :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SALES': ['B1','S1','S2']

                   })
df.head()
print(df)
```

I need to replace

```
B1 = BELTS
S1 = SHIRTS
S2 = SHOES
```

suggest me how to do

Comment: That's a typo. You can clearly see in SO that `print(SALES)` is in red because you haven't closed off your string in the previous line. Also, this is not pure python, is it Spark?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm new to python and I'm learning and trying to use case statement in python to get that result set

Comment: There is no `case` statement in Python. This not regular python and it's also a typo. Your comment doesn't address either point I made.

Comment: @roganjosh forgot about the CASE statement or typo  how can I achieve the result above in python ex  : replacing B1 with Belts and S1 with Shirts etc..;

Comment: I can't forget about the typo because _it's the reason you get `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`_, the focus of the question. And, for the last time; *is this Spark*? This is _not_ vanilla python; there are no "columns" in Python, `df` indicates Pandas but the camelCase method suggests another library. Please add the appropriate tags

Comment: @roganjosh let me change the question and get back to you so that you can answer according to that . I'm saying new to python and try to answer and help out

Comment: @roganjosh I have changed question to pandas Dataframe .can you please have a look now

Comment: You can update your dictionary with the items you need to replace before you create the dataframe

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh not that far I have reached in python . using dict all this stuff . can you please elaborate it and I see why people putting a question to negative ticks

Comment: Then I would suggest you to go through some basics first and then tackle a library like pandas, and read up on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) They are downvoting since the question was unclear before, now it sort of makes sense, but not much

Comment: @roganjosh if some one ask me question in SQLSERVER or SSIS I will not make them uncomfortable if they say they are new to the technology and more over I won't put the negative tick to reduce there score

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yeah sure I will go through but as of now   where is the answer for my question for god sake ..

Comment: Right, and you would welcome a discussion in which the OP says "Ignore both of the issues in my question, which isn't even about the language I've tagged it with" and then goes on to change the question to an entirely different library?

Comment: @roganjosh OK in this library how can I achieve it.. Just enlighten me on this

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html with a dictionary

Comment: What happened to SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how you can do that using dict to map the old and the new values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SALES': ['B1','S1','S2']})
df['SALES'].replace({'B1': 'BELTS', 'S1': 'SHIRTS', 'S2': 'SHOES'}, inplace=True)

df
Out[1]: 
    SALES
0   BELTS
1  SHIRTS
2   SHOES
```

If you want to keep the original DataFrame as it is, then skip the `inplace=True` and assign to new variable.